# Clash between MnSymbol and mathastext

Tags: math-mode, mnsymbol, mathastext

I can't seem to make these two packages play well. Is there a fix or should I just give up on it? Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{amsart}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage[frenchmath]{mathastext}
\begin{document}
Equation.
\begin{align*}
    \left( \bigoplus_i Z_i \right)
\end{align*} 
\end{document}
```

What ends up happening is that all big brackets become ].

I should say that this comes from my fixation of have having math text upright (plus the fact that documents should be uploadable to the arxiv). For a long time I used kpfonts, which was excellent, but I kind of got bored of the font.

Comment: Try loading the packages in the reverse order: `mathastext` first.

Comment: hah, it worked!

Comment: option `noparenthesis` would have excluded  `( ) [ ] / ` from the scope of  `mathatext`. (check the pdf doc for more excluding options). There is also option `basic` to limit its action to only letters and digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in my comment, reversing the order of package load (`mathastext` prior to `MnSymbol`) fixes the issue, giving both upright math variables as well as the `MnSymbol` paren delimiters and `\bigoplus`

```
\documentclass[oneside]{amsart}
\usepackage[frenchmath]{mathastext}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\begin{document}
Equation.
\begin{align*}
    \left( \bigoplus_i Z_i \right)
\end{align*} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

For comparison, here it is without `MnSymbol`:

[image]